# Apse divides central orbit into symmetrical portions

Tags: analytic-geometry, nonlinear-dynamics

I am solving dynamics and unable to digest author's views regarding apse. Help from the community is needed.

```
Theorem :- If the central acceleration p is a single valued function of the distance, 
every apse line divides the orbit into equal and symmetrical portions
```

Author's goes on to prove the below result

> v<sup>2</sup> = C - ∫ Pdr

{v - velocity ,
P - central acceleration ,
r - radial distance of particle assumed to be moving under the effect of central acceleration P ,
pole of the acceleration lies on origin}

Author states that since acceleration and velocity are single valued for r , they are same for same value of r.Hence the direction of motion is independent[understood and agreed].

So if the motion of the particle is reversed at a particular apse , it will trace a symmetrical orbital path on the other side of apsidal distance.[not understood]

**I accept that the particle upon changing the direction of motion will trace the same path from where it has arrived , it nowhere leads to the central orbit being symmetrical about the apse.**